# Plotting Cosine Function and Cosine Taylor Series on Subplot

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot the cosine function and the Taylor series for cosine on a subplot. I'm getting an error in my code saying that I haven't defined "symsum for input arguments of type 'double'". I don't know how to fix it.

```
x=0:10;
y1=cos(x);
y2=0;

for k=0:10
y2=y2+symsum((-1)^k*(x^(2*k))/factorial(2*k));
end

figure
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,y1)
title('Cosine')

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,y2)
title('Taylor Series')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include

```
    syms k
```

in your code to declare a symbolic variable k.
Also, the start and end to your sum should be included as arguments to symsum. Get rid of your for statement and include this instead:

```
    y2 = y2+symsum((-1)^k*(x^(2k))/factorial(2*k), 0, 10);
```